# How can I return several aggregates based on a condition within a queryset?

Tags: django

So I have the following model which contains different booleans and one `amount` field.
I now want to render the overall sum `amount` for each boolean when true (only one boolean will be true at once always).

```
class UserTransaction(models.Model):
    """
    A table to store transactions between a user and Farena
    """
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    offer = models.ForeignKey(Offer, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    amount = models.FloatField()
    is_deposit = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_withdrawal = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_interest = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_investment = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_return = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.user.first_name} {self.user.last_name} transacted {self.amount}'
```

I tried to build it with `annotate` but that would add fields for each instance which wouldn't solve my issue as far as I understand it. Additionally using `aggregate` I couldn't implement a condition and also wouldn't know how to access the aggregated value in the template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can aggregate over all the fields, so:

```
UserTransaction.objects.aggregate(
    total_deposit=Sum('is_deposit'),
    total_withdrawal=Sum('is_withdrawal'),
    total_interest=Sum('is_interest'),
    total_investment=Sum('is_investment'),
    total_return=Sum('is_return')
)
```

or for some databases where a bool is not implemented as an integer:

```
UserTransaction.objects.aggregate(
    total_deposit=Count('pk', filter=Q(is_deposit=True)),
    total_withdrawal=Count('pk', filter=Q(is_withdrawal=True)),
    total_interest=Count('pk', filter=Q(is_interest=True)),
    total_investment=Count('pk', filter=Q(is_investment=True)),
    total_return=Count('pk', filter=Q(is_return=True))
)
```

This will return a dictionary that looks like:

```
{
    'total_deposit': 14,
    'total_withdrawal': 25,
    'total_interest': 13,
    'total_investment': 2
    'total_return': 17
}
```

Comment: Thanks - But how can I actually access the dict in the template? Or do i have to provide it in the context?

Comment: @Jonas: Yes, you pass it through the context, for `context = {**result, 'other_key': 'other_value'}`, with `**result` the result of the aggregate, then you can render `{{ total_deposit }}` for example.

Comment: It seems the dict only contains `True` for each value per key -- hmm

Comment: @Jonas: what database do you use?

Comment: sqlite in development

Comment: @Jonas: then you should work with `Count`. I would advise to use the same database for development and production, since even the Django ORM does not always produces the same results for the same query among different dialects.

Comment: hmm count returns `5` for all since I have 5 instances in the table currently. So I think I cant make it work with the current setup

Comment: @Jonas: what Django version do you use? `filter=...` was introduced in [tag:Django-2.0] iirc.

Comment: I'm on Django 4.0.3

Comment: @Jonas: did you use `filter=Q(is_deposit=True)` in the `Count('pk', ...)`? You did use `Count`? Not `Sum(..)`?

Comment: No I just replaced `Sum` with `Count` in your previous answer -- :-/

Comment: Now that returns `1` for each key in the dict - but anyways appreciate the support, dont wanna bother you too long :)

Comment: @Jonas: but is there one item for each key? Did you filter on the different fields?

Comment: I added my current setup to the post

Comment: I got it. I used your solution with the Q parameter and replaced `Count` with `Sum` I guess this was not your intention so probably a typo - thanks!